# Writing the Laplace's equation solution as the Poisson kernel integral

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I had to solve $\Delta u=0$ in the semi infinite strip $S=\{(x,y) |0<x<1,0<y \}$ with boundaries condition 
$$
u(x,0)=f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_n \sin(\pi n x), ~u(0,y)=u(1,y)=0
$$
then it gaves another condition that leads to the solution $u_n(x,y)=a_ne^{-\pi n y}\sin(\pi nx)$, and then to the general solution $$
u(x,y)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_ne^{-\pi n y}\sin(\pi nx)
$$

Then the exercise asks to write $u(x,y)$ as a integral involving $f$, like the Poisson integral formula $$
u(r,\theta)=f*P_r(\theta),
$$ 
$P_r$ the Poisson kernel.

This last part is the one that I can't solve.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any integral formulation comes from the explicit use of the Fourier coefficients:
$$
    a_n = 2\int_{0}^{1}f(u)\sin(n\pi u)du
$$
Then
$$
       u(x,y)=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(u)\sin(n\pi u)du\sin(n\pi x)e^{-n\pi y} \\
   = \int_{0}^{1}f(u)\left[2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n\pi u)\sin(n\pi x)e^{-n\pi y}\right]du
$$